# Module not found: Can't resolve '@your-org/core-lib' in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, yarnpkg, monorepo

I am new in monorepo or yarn workspace .So learning I follow this starter boilerplate

https://github.com/belgattitude/nextjs-monorepo-example

I forked the above example .And run `yarn` command on root folder .Initially I got this error
**Couldn't find package "@your-org/core-lib@workspace:*"**

I resolved above error by using version instead of **`*`**
I resolve above error like this

```
 "@your-org/ui-lib": "3.1.2",
  "@your-org/core-lib": "3.2.2",
```

instead of

```
"@your-org/ui-lib": "workspace:*",
"@your-org/core-lib": "workspace:*",
```

Then when I run `yarn` my all packages are installed on root directory.when I move inside directory using `cd apps/blog-app` and run `yarn dev` .my application run perfectly and show the first page.

NOTE : I don't start anything like example `ui-lib` and `core-lib`.but when I change anything on `core-lib` .it automatically reflecting .Not sure how it is happening without `watch` or `build` command. ??

Now I create a new nextjs app in `apps` folder.
I used this command `yarn create next-app --typescript` with a name of `new-app`.
but when I run `yarn dev` it is successfully build and run .but I am trying to use this `"@your-org/core-lib"` package in my new app .I am getting module not found error.

I have already used `yarn add @your-org/core-lib` in `new-app` directory not on root directory but this still getting same error
**Module not found: Can't resolve '@your-org/core-lib' ?**

```
"dependencies": {
    "next": "11.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "@your-org/core-lib": "3.2.2"
  }
```

I am using like this

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import { sayHello } from '@your-org/core-lib';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
 <ul>
          <li>{`Foo says: ${sayHello('World')} from @your-org/core-lib`}</li>
        </ul>
    

     
    </div>
```

here is my whole code
https://replit.com/@naveennsit/nextjs-monorepo-example#apps/new-app/pages/index.tsx

kindly suggest where I am doing wrong?
any sugesstion